# Authenticating to a Oauth 2-legged system

Tags: java, ruby, oauth, 2-legged

I'm trying to authenticate to a webservice using 2legged oauth. I have the next one working java example creating the authenticated URL using the [signpost](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) library:

```
 String consumerKey = "KEY";
 String consumerSecret = "SECRET";
 DefaultOAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
 consumer.setTokenWithSecret(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
 return consumer.sign(targetUrl);
```

And this generates an URL like this

http://example.com/my/method?oauth_consumer_key=KEY&oauth_nonce=4779611081457530684&oauth_signature=v19lL74VVMTibCMja5vnwIE2q5g%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1368778106&oauth_token=KEY&oauth_version=1.0

And I'm trying to recreate it using ruby's [oauth](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/). My code looks now like this:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@creds[:key], @creds[:secret],
                               :site => "URL",
                               :scheme => :query_string)
token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer)
token.get "METHOD"
```

And generates URLS like:

http://example.com/my/method?oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_nonce=7eQe4cAE27uBE9Bftfx7Pcjj1kqfuXHPWt5d3NZw0&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_consumer_key=KEY&oauth_timestamp=1368778250&oauth_signature=EbM0BjslzB5yXYWeC8EJGAEGi1k%3D

But I'm always getting an Unauthorized error, even if I manually set oauth_token to key (as signpost do). Looks like the nonce is invalid, but both of them are valid libraries to oauth

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd been the same problem with 2-legged oauth, I fixed with:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(key, secret, { :site => 'http://api.mysite.com' })
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, :oauth_token => key, :oauth_token_secret => secret)
```

Common issues comes from out of sync timestamps

Your requests must be synchronized with the server system clock, for instance in linkedin must be within 5 minutes of her system clock.

Hope it helps ;)